# MySQL adding a 4th table to SELECT messes up results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have never triple joined, and I'm pretty bad in SQL, and I messed up something.

```
Tables:

article - 
   id(pk), publicist_id(fk - publicist.id), title, synopsys, text, status ...

publicist - 
   id(pk), name ... + stuff that doesn't matter 

rating - 
   id(pk), article_id(fk - article.id), article_rating 

(and later on) comment - 
   id(pk), author, text, article_id(fk - article.id), status ...
```

status is just a tinyInt to see if it's active or not.

So far I was using this (article, publicist, rating):

```
SELECT article.id, 
article.title, 
article.synopsys, 
publicist.name, 
IFNULL(CAST(AVG(rating.article_rating) AS DECIMAL(10,2)),0) AS avg_rating, 
IFNULL(COUNT(rating.article_rating),0) AS number_of_ratings 
FROM article 
JOIN publicist ON publicist.id = publicist_id 
JOIN rating ON rating.article_id = article.id 
GROUP BY article.id;
```

Which worked fine for the purpose, as showing title, synopsys, name, avg rating(2 decimals), and number of ratings on an article.

Now I have to also include the number of comments on each article, and I just can't manage.
Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT a.id, 
a.title, 
a.synopsys, 
p.name, 
IFNULL(CAST(AVG(r.article_rating) AS DECIMAL(10,2)),0) AS avg_rating,
IFNULL(COUNT(r.article_rating),0) AS number_of_ratings,
IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN c.status = 1 THEN 1 END),0) AS number_of_comments    -- this is new
FROM article a
JOIN publicist p ON p.id = a.publicist_id
LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.article_id = a.id     -- LEFT JOIN here
LEFT JOIN comment c ON c.article_id = a.id    -- this is new
GROUP BY a.id;
```

I tried to also only count the comments where the status is set to 1, not that it mattered.
So far what it does is messes up my rating numbers from the previous version, seems like it throws around random numbers both in number_of_ratings, and in number_of_comments,

E.g:
article1 with 7 ratings and 3 comments
article2 with 3 ratings and 3 comments (2 active, 1 not)
article1:
`1st version: number_of_ratings: 7`
`2nd version: number_of_ratings: 14, comments: 14`
article1:
`1st version: number_of_ratings: 3`
`2nd version: number_of_ratings: 9, comments: 6`

I have no idea how to fix this or even why it behaves like this.
Also, am I on the right path with `COUNT(CASE WHEN c.status = 1 THEN 1 END)` ?

Thank you!

Comment: 'Join multiplying'. Count in subquery then join.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I didn't know about Join multiplying. Umberto-petrov is using this method in his answer, and it works wonderfully.

Comment: @Strawberry, Thank you, I'm kind of new here, I'll be paying more attention to my post quality in the future.

Comment: No time like the present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can count the comments per article in a subquery and then join to it:

```sql
SELECT article.id, 
article.title, 
article.synopsys, 
publicist.name, 
IFNULL(CAST(AVG(rating.article_rating) AS DECIMAL(10,2)),0) AS avg_rating, 
IFNULL(COUNT(rating.article_rating),0) AS number_of_ratings ,
IFNULL(c.CommentCount,0) AS number_of_comments    --NEW
FROM article 
JOIN publicist ON publicist.id = publicist_id 
JOIN rating ON rating.article_id = article.id 
JOIN (                                            --NEW
  SELECT article_id, COUNT(*) as CommentCount
  FROM comment
  GROUP BY article_id
) c ON article.id = c.article_id
GROUP BY article.id;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonderfully. Switched last 2 JOINs to LEFT JOINS so articles with 0 ratings/comments show up as well.